# Python: Call a constructor whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: python, constructor

I have the following variable:

```
var = 'MyClass'
```

I would like to create an object of `MyClass` based on the variable `var`. Something like `var()`. How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def hello():
...     print "hello world"
... 
>>> globals()["hello"]()
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have the class' module as a variable as well, you can do the following, where the class you want "MyClass" resides in module "my.module":

```
def get_instance(mod_str, cls_name, *args, **kwargs):
    module = __import__(mod_str, fromlist=[cls_name])
    mycls = getattr(module, cls_name)

    return mycls(*args, **kwargs)


mod_str = 'my.module'
cls_name = 'MyClass'

class_instance = get_instance(mod_str, cls_name, *args, **kwargs)
```

This function will let you get an instance of any class, with whatever arguments the constructor needs, from any module available to your program.